# Unable to search with underscore '_' using odata startswith function

Tags: sql, filter, odata

I have a query, that ends like this:

```
..?$filter=startswith(COLUMN_NAME,"SomeValue_") eq true
```

When this is translated by my query engine, the SQL is created like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SomeValue_'
```

As you can see, it treats '_' as a place holder, like qith any SQL, otherwise the correct query should be made like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SomeValue\_' ESCAPE '\'
```

So, how do I specify in ODATA that the underscore '_' should be treated as a character in my query engine instead of as a place holder? Or can I specify in ODATA to escape this underscore? I tried encoding it with its hex value, it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also facing this problem in 2020, and unable to find the solution. If somebody may point in the right direction, please!

Comment: @BhaveshDiwan Sorry, I don't remember what did I end up doing, its been so long. I don't think I found any solution though! Please post it here if you do find one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bellow link would help you.

[Link](http://www.techtamasha.com/escape-single-quotes-and-wild-cards-_-in-ms-sql/20)

Comment: I have already stated this. The link you shared shows how to do it through SQL, which I have already mentioned in my question. I need to do this through ODATA.